# how to add bootstrap-alert box inside a javascript?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, alert

I have a JavaScript with alert box saying some text when an image is uploaded with wrong dimension.I want to show that alert as a Bootstrap alert instead of a popup window?

I have a separate JavaScript file.

Comment: Maybe you will find http://bootboxjs.com/ useful

Answer (score 1):

In Bootstrap they're not called "pop ups", but instead modals. Its the same general principle (a alert onto the screen for the user to interact with), but just more pretty. See the link below for more information on modals, and the code as well (fully functional). Hope this helps. - Jusitn

Link: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp

Edit: Dont forget to add the bootstrap CDN's for it to work (both the CSS and Javascript CDNs) between your head tags

CDN can be found here: http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/

Code:

```
<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hai, Justin , What I need is to show that alert as what exactly the <div class= "alert alert-warning"> will do .. I want to include  that in an external javascript file.. can you get me .. ?

Comment: so you want the modal to look like alert alert-warning ?

Comment: yes,Exactly ,any way to achieve it ? I need to implement that in an external javascript file ...

Comment: on the line that says "<div class = "modal-dialog"> try: <div class = "modal-dialog alert alert-warning">.

Comment: As far as implementing it in a external JS file, you would need to load the file into your HTML with the <script src=""></script>, then where ever you want the modal to be, create that element (like a <div></div>) but assign it to a id (so like <div id ="myDiv"></div>). Then in your external JS file, call document.getElementById("myDiv") with the approiate method and insert it

Comment: look up on w3 schools on using GetElementById , that will get you pointed in the right direction